# Why can i define a new cond, and Scheme will not get confused with my new cond over the conditional cond?

Tags: scheme, evaluator, metacircular

I have this task where i'm working with a metacircular evaluator, and i define a new `cond` like this:

```
(define cond 3)
```

As well as `else`:

```
(define (else x) (/ x 2)
```

My question is why does this (below) actually work?

```
(cond ((= cond 2) 0) 
(else (else 4)))
```

How does Scheme know which `cond` is my defined cond and my `else`, over the conditional `cond` and `else`?

(Feel free to edit the title, as i'm not sure how to formulate my question)

Comment: At least in Racket, it definitely does not. Both `cond` and both `else` identifiers are bound to the new definitions, and the expressions throws an exception for trying to apply `3` as a procedure.

Comment: Where does that work? As far as I know, it shouldn't work in any Scheme implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you have implemented `cond` in the metacircular evaluator. Usually it checks some operators for symbols like `quote` and `cond` and then do someething special. Thus `cond` in operator position will be expanded as `cond` while `cond` in other circumstances would be evaluated as if it was a variable.

Answer (score 1):

In Scheme there are no reserved identifiers. In many languages there is a list of reserved identifiers (keywords) that can't be used as names of variables.

In Scheme you can for example do this:

```
> (let ((cond +))
    (cond 1 2))
3
```

What sets Scheme apart from most languages is that programs are macro expanded.

Running a Scheme program:

```
read -> macro expansion -> compilation -> execution
```

It is non-trivial to explain how the macro expansion algorithm works.
I can recommend the chapter "Syntactic Abstraction: The syntax-case expander" by R. Kent Dybvig in the book "Beautiful Code".

https://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/bc-syntax-case.pdf